# Twilio SMS Error 2003 in asp.net C# app

Tags: c#, asp.net, twilio

I have been going back and forth with Twilio support with no resolution as of yet. I can log into their site and send an SMS message to my verified phone number but when I do it from my web app I get the error 2003 - Permission denied in the rest exception. Here is my code:

```
string ACCOUNT_SID = "SID";
string AUTH_TOKEN = "TOKEN";

TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

client.SendMessage("TO", "FROM", "Testing SMS message http://www.google.com", "null");
```

The only thing that looks strange to me is in their code on the site there are 5 parameters passed to SendMessage and my method call only allows for 4. Has anyone run into this issue? I ran this identical code last year with a trial membership and it worked.

### TWILIO

```
 using System; 
 using Twilio; 
 class Example 
  { 
      static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
      // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account 
        string AccountSid = "ACec77e078a76246d83947d21cd5fa8aba"; 
        string AuthToken = "[AuthToken]"; 
        var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken); 

        var message = twilio.SendMessage("+14025780621", "[To]", null, null, null); 
          Console.WriteLine(message.Sid); 
             } 
          }
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you found that example Twilio code, but all those null parameters appear to be optional anyways. You said you got error code 2003, but I'm pretty sure you meant error code 20003. That's described [on their documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/20003), and indicates you didn't authenticate correctly. Double check your SID and token.

Comment: Ive triple checked them and used every combination possible. The example came from their test app on their website.

Comment: I get that they are optional I am just wondering do I have a different version of the twilio dll, I installed it from NuGet so I assumed it was the latest.

Comment: I fixed the permission error but now I get this error code = Error - 21609. Invalid StatusCallback URL
The StatusCallback URL provided is not a valid URL.
Possible Solutions
Make sure you submit a fully qualified URL including:
protocol (http:// or https://)
hostname    ---   Im not passing in a callback url.

Comment: Your error seems pretty self explanatory. You must provide a URL to it that's valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the 21609 error try:

client.SendMessage("TO", "FROM", "Testing SMS message http://www.google.com", null);

(I removed the quotes around the 4th argument null).

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for the help. I was able to solve this today by completely removing the null param. Twilio's support lacks technical knowledge and they led me in the wrong direction several times. The thing that threw me off the most was they gave me incorrect test authentication keys.